# ccTouchesMoved adds object to array multiple times, even though an if statement should avoid that

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

If the ccTouchesMoved function is called, the sprites that are in the scope of the moving finger have to be added to an array. But only ONCE. I get the result that it adds the touched sprite multiple times (because the finger is still on the sprite when it's moved toward the outside of the sprite). So I encapsulated it into an if statement, which should avoid that. But it doesn't ... What should I do ?

```
-(void) ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *myTouch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [myTouch locationInView:[myTouch view]];
    CGPoint convertedLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];

    CCSprite* realSprite = [self whichHexagonTouched:convertedLocation];

    NSNumber *hexTag = [NSNumber numberWithInt:realSprite.tag];

    // If the hexagon is not in the array and not nil, it should destroy it and add it to the array

    if(realSprite != nil && ![hexTags containsObject:hexTag]){
        [self destroyHexagon:realSprite];    
        [hexTags addObject:hexTag];

        NSLog(@"these are the hexTags %@", hexTags);
        } 


}
```

Comment: Why store the tag in the array, why not just store the realSprite?

Comment: Does it make any difference ? I am checking with `![hexTags containsObject:hexTag]` whether it already contains the tag that had been added before... If I were to compare objects it would not make any difference, right ?

Comment: That's why this is a comment, not an answer; it just seemed like quite a lot of effort to make an object per movement just to see if it's already in an array :)

Comment: well ,thank you anyway :) ... I hope I am going to solve that soon...

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `NSSet` (or `NSMutableSet`) instead? Unless you want to preserve the order in which the sprites are added to the list, `NSMutableSet` is better suited for your case. You don't even have to check if the sprites have been added to the list or not because it is done internally by the `NSMutableSet`. Also, calling `containsObject:` on an `NSSet` is optimized since it uses object hashes.

Comment: Actually, the order has to be preserved... But thank you anyway